# Изменить id дочерних элементов при клонировании div

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Добрый день!

Используя jQuery, мне нужно клонировать div и заменить в нем у всех дочерних элементов name (у полей ввода) и id.

вот мой код, который пока только клонирует:

```
 $("#payment").clone().appendTo(".form").attr( "id", "payment" + FieldCount);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при клонировании менять у склонированных в дочерних элементах параметры name или  id.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Официальная документация не рекомендует клонировать элементы с id, но [умельцы на stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331197/) нашлись.

От себя хотелось бы добавить [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/94Lp4q7d/), в котором по кнопке можно делать клонирование исходного блока со сменой у всех элементов (и у родительского) id на уникальное значение.